# Unable to set Sharepoint site to read only when archiving teams with Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to archive a large number of teams with Microsoft graph while at the same time setting the Sharepoint sites to read only. This can be done by adding `"shouldSetSpoSiteReadOnlyForMembers": true` to the body of the request.

For example:

```
"uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/3692e87f-d7a9-4832-8cba-700309277f88/archive",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "*sanitized*"
},
"body": {
    "shouldSetSpoSiteReadOnlyForMembers": true
}
```

This works for some teams but not for others. Graph returns a 400 error with the message:

```
Tenant/teams service Admin Could not update Sharepoint site permissions / archival state because the team's site url is not available.
```

The sites exist and their url's havent been changed.